# Format from decimal to money SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need this type of decimal number format because what I show refers to money. SP SQL Server 2019

I need to transform from this $25,000.00 a $25.000,00.

Someone could help me?

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,CAST(@MontoFinal AS money),1),'.',','),',','.') = 117.692.05
```

Comment: The correct place to do that is in your front end, not the database.

Comment: In a database you should have the numeric value, and then you should format it in whichever script or application you're using to query the data. The `$` symbol makes the value a string, which means that your Sql probably can't quantify it numerically.

Comment: And whats not working about your existing code?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is usually best handled by the UI, but sometimes you have to do it in the database for various reasons. Sometimes you have to live with mandates, and if you have to do it in the database, it can be done.

Looking at your desired output, you want periods as separators and a comma as a decimal point, and you would also like a dollar sign. Luckily for you, this is how Argentina formats its currency, so you can just use the built-in `FORMAT` function. The culture string for Argentina is `es-AR`, so you can use that along with `FORMAT`:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(123456789, 'C', 'es-AR') AS [Example];
```

This yields:

| Example |
| --- |
| $ 123.456.789,00 |

If your data is a number, you are done. If it is stored as text like in your example, you can `CAST` it as you were doing:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('$25,000.00' AS MONEY), 'C', 'es-AR') AS [Example];
```

Which gives your desired output:

| Example |
| --- |
| $ 25.000,00 |

As a final note, the `FORMAT` function in this scenario puts a space between the dollar sign and the leading number - if you don't want the space, you can remove it:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(CAST('$25,000.00' AS MONEY), 'C', 'es-AR'), ' ', '') AS [Example];
```

And that gives you:

| Example |
| --- |
| $25.000,00 |

There are other ways to get a similar result, but this is probably the easiest (I said easiest, I did not say anything about performance).

If your data is actually text and already has the correct commas and decimal points along with the dollar sign, you could use `REPLACE` - first replace `.` with something (I used `_`), then `REPLACE` the `,` with `.`, and finally `REPLACE` the `_` with `.` :

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('$25,000.00', '.', '_'), ',', '.'), '_', ',') AS [Example];
```

And again it gives your desired output:

| Example |
| --- |
| $25.000,00 |

If your data is not in a consistent format to start with correct commas and decimal points, the `FORMAT` approach will probably work better for you.